# Why async/await and then produce different results

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, promise

I'm just asking this question to clarify and get a better understanding at javascript promises. The following two codes look very similar to me, but why both gives different results. Also how to get the result of **async/await** function in **.then** way. Thanks.

**async/await**

```
const getFieldValue = async (collection, userid) => {
  let response;

  const querySnapshot = await firestore()
    .collection(collection)
    .where("userid", "==", userid)
    .get();
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const { name } = doc.data();
    response = name;
  });

  return response;
};
```

```
async function fetchData() {
  const name = await getFieldValue("Users", userid);
  console.log("name", name);
}
fetchData();
```

**.then**

```
const getFieldValue = (collection, userid) => {
  let response;

  firestore()
    .collection(collection)
    .where("userid", "==", userid)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.find((doc) => {
        const { name } = doc.data();
        response = name;
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

  return response;
};
```

```
const name = getFieldValue("Users", userid);
console.log("name", name);
```

**async/await** returns correct name and **.then** returns undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep that's just what one would expect.

Remember, `await` effectively suspends execution until the awaited operation is complete.

In your example using `.then` you return immediately because you did not compose your promise chain such that `response` is returned only when the sequence of awaited operations completes. Rather, you return immediately with the `undefined` value with which `response` was initialized

Thus, the proper way to express your logic, otherwise unaltered, via `.then` would be

```
 const getFieldValue = (collection, userid) => {
    let response;

    return firestore() // notice the return here! This is vital
      .collection(collection)
      .where("userid", "==", userid)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {           
        querySnapshot.docs.find((doc) => {
          const { name } = doc.data();
          response = name;
        });
      })
      .then(() => response) // notice how we resolve our promise chain with the value ultimately assigned
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

Comment: Yep this promises is frustrating. I did knew about promise chaining but don't have enough understanding on how it works. Thanks.

Comment: They're not frustrating once you understand how they work but you might as well stick with await for readability unless you're parallelizing

Comment: Yes, can you recommend me the uses cases where we should use promises and where to use await

Comment: That's slightly out of scope, and is somewhat contested, but my advice would be to use the async await syntactic sugar unless you want to enter leave a bunch of asynchronous operations, running them in parallel as it were.

Answer (score 1):

Because with **async/await** the execution of the **function is suspended ("paused"), until the promise is resolved**. Therefore your funcion waits for the result.

With **.then** however, your **function will continue immediately** with the code below the .then "block", **not waiting for the promise to resolve**. Because of that response is returned before it is set in the .then section and therefore still undefined.

With async/await you have to imagine that the return statement is also in the .then block.